# Why does Visual Studio 2019 change the case of some letters in a branch I created in ADO?

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I created a branch in Azure DevOps (ADO) with all lower case letters:  alwayson/user/jr/870397.
I then went to Visual Studio 2019 and did a Fetch in Team Explorer.
In Team Explorer, I then filtered branches on "870397".  What Visual Studio showed was a branch on the remote where the  'a' and the 'o' had been changed to upper-case:  AlwaysOn/user/jr/870397.

Why does VS do this case changing, and is there a way to prevent it from doing so?  I couldn't find a setting or related property anywhere in VS.

Comment: Is it possible both branches exist?

Answer (score 1):

Azure itself should not change anything.

[Its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/case-sensitivity?view=azure-devops) even includes:

> ### Branch and tag names
>
> You can create two branches or tags (known as 'refs') that differ only in casing.
> Git's internals, as well as Azure DevOps Services/TFS, will treat them as two separate refs. On a user's machine, Git uses the filesystem to store refs.
>
> Fetches and other operations begin to fail because of the ambiguity. Each ref is represented by a small file, and if a ref name contains `/` characters, the parts before the final `/` are represented by folders.
>
> One simple way to avoid issues is to always use all-lowercase branch and tag names. If you have already created two branches or tags with this problem, you can fix it in the Azure Repos web UI.

So double-check the full list of branches with `git branch -avv` locally to see what you have fetched.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't appear to shed any light for me on the resolution.

Comment: @BlackRockJohnny What does `git branch -avv` return?